# CSS/Bootstrap: How to stretch containers within cols full-height?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm using the simple Bootstrap-Grid: one row, two `col-md-6`-columns. Within each column I've a container `class="box"`, which should use a `height of 100%`.

I tried different ways, e.g. simulating a table and table-cols, but chose the `.row-eq-height`-class, recommended by Bootstrap.

Whats the common way to force the `box` within `col-md-6` to stretch to full-height?

HTML:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box" style="background: red">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.            
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="box" style="background: green">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-eq-height {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.col-md-6 {
  background: yellow; /* to show the left space */
}

.box {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Live:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmbe4h1h/

Edit: I would like to avoid wrapping the HTML with additional containers (like in many `position: relative/absolute`-tutorials).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ManojKumar In the example (fiddle) the red container is higher than the green container. Maybe you need to reduce your browsers  width, to be able to see the issue.

Comment: You mean the content is higher right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a proper CSS solution for my case and switched to

**JS (*jQuery*)**:

```
$('.sameHeightWrapper').each(function() {
    var highestContainer = 0;
    $('.sameHeightContainer', this).each(function() {
        if($(this).height() > highestContainer) {
            highestContainer = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    $('.sameHeightContainer', this).height(highestContainer);
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="sameHeightWrapper">
    <div class="sameHeightContainer c1">
        Container 1<br/>
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="sameHeightContainer c2">
        Container 2<br/>
        ...
    </div>   
    <div class="sameHeightContainer c3">
        Container 3<br/>
        Container 3<br/>
        ...
    </div>   
</div>
```

Try it: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/bb4xwLqd/)

Answer (score 0):

[CSS solution](http://jsfiddle.net/TechNinja/cmbe4h1h/1/). removed the padding on the `col-md-6` class. also moved your bg inline style to the outer container, not the `box` class.

[More Reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287206/same-height-column-bootstrap-3-row-responsive)