# bootstrap layout row with different heights

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

i want to add bootstrap row with `col-lg-3`class. my  `div` contains different heights.hope to add articles with different length texts. 
[my output is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXUck.jpg)  but designed [expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jg6eP.jpg) and  here. code as follows

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #c5d5cb"><p style="height: 150px">1</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #9fa8a3"><p style="height: 200px">2</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #e3e0cf"><p style="height: 50px">3</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #b3c2bf"><p style="height: 60px">4</p></div>  

    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #173e43"><p style="height: 44px">5</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #b56969"><p style="height: 70px">6</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #daad86"><p style="height: 20px">7</p></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3" style="background-color: #5a5c51"><p style="height: 35px">8</p></div> 
</div>
```

**Updated** 
values put as 1,2,3 etc comes from mysql database. so the  height is equal to text row numbers. php code is follows 
`

```
    foreach ($value as $add) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-3'><p>";
        echo $add->item;
        echo "</p></div>";
    }
    ?>`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Same height column bootstrap 3 row responsive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287206/same-height-column-bootstrap-3-row-responsive)

Comment: End your previous question and start again with new question to make it clear question

Comment: This question is not well exposed and needs clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps, I ruin your original code. I change everywhere. I hope this helps you.

1. Add customized stylesheet inside tag head:

`<style>
    .col-md-3{padding:0px;} // default: 15px -> left and right.
</style>`

2. Here's the code:

`<div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #c5d5cb;height: 150px;">
                        1
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #173e43;height: 44px; color:white;">
                        5
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #9fa8a3;height: 200px;">
                        2
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #b56969;height: 70px;">
                        6
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #e3e0cf;height: 50px;">
                        3
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #daad86;height: 20px;">
                        7
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #b3c2bf;height: 60px;">
                        4
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12" style="background-color: #5a5c51;height: 35px;">
                        8
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>`

Because I don't know what version of your bootstrap, I use `v3.1.1` for `clearfix` ... you can customize this based on your version.

Comment: it's work perfectly.. @herman do u have idea to put these `div` in a sql result   `<div class="row">
        <?php

        foreach ($value as $add) {
            echo "<div class='col-md-3'><p>";
            echo $add->item;
            echo "</p></div>";

        }
        ?>
    </div>` i mean all <P> values comes from database, height is no of  text rows.

Comment: Final this question first then start again with your new question since your question has no related to mysql script. Besides, future members will read this and see if the question has been solved

Answer (score 1):

You are on right track. This will definitely work. You need to use col-md-3 like this :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>5</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <p>2</p>
   <p>6</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <p>3</p>
   <p>7</p>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
   <p>4</p>
   <p>8</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think try this

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-5">
   <div id="1"  ></div>
   <div id="5"  ></div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
   <div id="2"  ></div>
   <div id="6"  ></div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
   <div id="3"  ></div>
   <div id="7"  ></div>
  </div>
<div class="col-lg-5">
   <div id="4"  ></div>
   <div id="8"  ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained why this works instead of just a code dump with 'try this'...

Answer (score 0):

You can first use columns with `col-lg-3` and then place your blocks inside each one. That way you will get your desired result.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 grid-row">
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #c5d5cb"><p style="height: 150px">1</p></div>
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #173e43"><p style="height: 44px">5</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 grid-row">
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #9fa8a3"><p style="height: 200px">2</p></div>
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #b56969"><p style="height: 70px">6</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 grid-row">
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #e3e0cf"><p style="height: 50px">3</p></div>
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #daad86"><p style="height: 20px">7</p></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 grid-row">
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #b3c2bf"><p style="height: 60px">4</p></div>
      <div class="left-block" style="background-color: #5a5c51"><p style="height: 35px">8</p></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.grid-row{
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.left-block{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/debraj/6dufsc4u/1/

Hope that helps.