# Equal heights per row

Tags: jquery

I would like to set equal heights on all items. I am currently using this example:

```
   var heights = $(".well").map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    $(".well").height(maxHeight);
```

Based on this question [Same height column bootstrap 3 row responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287206/same-height-column-bootstrap-3-row-responsive)

I would like to apply this on a per row basis, as some heights are being set too high for rows that do not need so be set.

Comment: Does it have to be done by jQuery? Because `flexbox` is [widely supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) since then (2014).

Comment: Check @Popnoodles answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For examples sake Lets assume you are out putting your html via a php loop (if not then you can simply loop though the elems assigning a class) same principle applies.

PHP example outputting html

```
    <?php foreach($array as $k => $v): ?>
        <?php if($k % (4) == 0) $class++; ?>

        <div class="row-num-<?php echo $class ?>">
            // div content variable height
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

jQuery Setting Equal Height per row using your existing code

```
        var totalFrames = $('div[class*=row-num-]').length;
        for ( var i = 1, l = totalFrames; i < l; i++ ) {
            var heights = $(".row-num-"+i).map(function() {
                    return $(this).height();
                }).get(),

                maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

            $(".row-num-"+i).height(maxHeight);
        }
```

This assumes your row is 4 elems wide. You can set this or dynamically calc it depending on your use. In the jQuery we loop through all elems with a class like `row-num-` then we target each one setting the height. These will have the same class every four elems. It continues until the current count of this class name has been reached.

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18026/

Comment: This works flawlessly - The only issue I have is that it isn't responsive as the columns will not always be 4 wide.

Comment: This can be responsive. That number can be dynamically calculated. You could also put this in a function and invoke on window resize. I don't know your set-up, are the columns going full width of the page or just contained within a small div within the page. My code will need tailored to your needs. It's a proof of concept example.

Answer (score 3):

well its possible with css also if you use `display:flex` on parent div then all the inner div will come with same height in same row but if its need of jquery then use this

**CODE**

```
var maxHeight;
$(".well").each(function(){
  if($(this).height > maxHeight){
    maxHeight = $(this).height;// will assign the highest height to this
  }
})
$('.well').css('height',maxHeight );
```

All the div will be of same height according to the highest size div

Comment: it should definately work i am using it on so many places so please share your codes

Comment: Thanks - Here is an example of it not working for me https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18022/

Comment: well sorry for my silly mistakes in previous code here is the new link and working file https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18027/

Comment: Thanks but this does exactly the same was what my code currently does. It isn't on a per row basis. Vector's answer does what I want https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18026/ but I need to modify it so it's responsive which is why i wanted a simpler solution.